# Too dark shadows

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

This is what I made, multiple boxes (the default box), default camera and lamps.

[image: viewport]

And when I render, it looks like this:

[image: render]

Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't I see the different boxes? Is it normal that the shadows are so dark that they hide all edges?

Comment: Add more lamps...

Comment: You only have 2 lamps, the sides of the cubes that are rendering black have nothing to illuminate them.

Comment: Also render could be too dark without global illumination (secondary light bounces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have enough lamps at the right positions (as said in the comments by someonewithpc and PGmath). You can fix this in various ways:

1. Just keep adding/duplicating more point lamps, and spread them around.
2. Keep only one lamp, and set its mode to Sun.
3. Have two lamps, one of them a Sun lamp (like in #2), and the other one a Hemi light. Then set the energy of the hemi light to ~0.2, and the energy of the sun light to ~0.8. That way you will illuminate all the faces (so no pure black), and will have shadows. (**Note**: If you add lights from the 'Create' menu, then you will have no shadows by default. Enable them by scrolling down, and selecting 'Ray Shadow' (only present on the Sun light))

[image]